# How to validate email with this code?

Tags: validation, contact-form

I have made code with is work great for me, but I want to make email validation to require @ on the field. Here is the code

```
if (!$('#contact_email').val()) {

        if ($("#contact_email").parent().next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
        {
            $("#contact_email").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Ange e-postadress</div>");
        }
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent form from POST to server
        $('#contact_email').focus();
        focusSet = true;
    } else {
        $("#contact_email").parent().next(".validation").remove(); // remove it
    }
```

And the input is

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E-post" name="Email" id="contact_email" onblur="validate()">
```

I dont use basic email field because I don't want to be on english.
How can i implement @ to be required on this text input. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Use This function:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return re.test(email);
```

}

found here:

[Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to check for an "@" and a "." field.

Regex:

```
var regex= /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
return regex.test(email);
```

The above code will return true if the regular expression is matched. This expression checks for an `@` and a `.` to be present in the given string.
Heres the documentation on `.test` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

I've noticed other answers have better regular expressions as the above will allow for multiple `@`'s and `.`'s to be present.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for email validation:

```
function isEmail(email) {
        var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if (email.match(mailformat)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Checking as follows:

```
if (email != "") {
                if (!isEmail(email)) {
                    alert("invalid");
                }
            }
```

Comment: I hope it works for you. It will do email validations!!